# Avoid session spamming from crawlers and other bots

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

Since crawlers and most bots don't use cookies, they create a lot of unnecessary sessions. At least for identified bots we'd like to avoid creating a session.

We're using SqlInMemoryProvider which doesn't appear to be open source.
https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2014/07/10/new-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-sql-server-in-memory-oltp/

Is there a way to run code to intercept session creation for certain conditions? My guess is one would need access to the custom SqlInMemoryProvider to achieve that. But maybe i'm missing something. ;)

Technology: Asp.Net Webforms, don't bother advising for MVC, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer for other people in my situation.

There are no hooks.
Everything needs to be done in the custom session-state store provider.

It's possible to use the free disassembler DotPeek by JetBrains.
One can dissassemble an existing state provider to c# code.
After that the code can be extended, for example detect known bots with a library (for example) https://github.com/totpero/DeviceDetector.NET and prevent such sessions from being created.